# Reload Rails code when using foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, foreman

when using `rails s`, when code changes, rails reloads those files, so I don't need to stop and start the server again.

When using foreman via `foreman start -p 3000` to test background workers, every time I change their code, I need to restart foreman.

Is there a way to reload code with foreman automagically?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) gem.

Basic steps:

```
gem install rerun
rerun foreman start
```